# Why java throws exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a code which reads data from a file and inserts it into database.

this code writes the data into a file.

```
public void save(Collection<Book> b) {
    try (PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(this.file);) {
        for (Book book : b) {
            String str = book.getName() + "," + book.getAuthor() + ","
                    + book.getDate() + "\n";
            print.println(str);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

this code writes the data from the a file and inserts it into db.

```
try(Reader reader = new FileReader(this.file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myBook", this.userName,
                this.pass);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String str;          
        while((str = br.readLine()) != null){

            String[] array = str.split(",");
            statement.executeUpdate("Insert Into myBook.book (name,author,pubDate) values('"+array[0]+"', '"+ array[1]+"', '"+array[2]+"')");
        }

    }
```

But it throws Exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

What is wrong?

Comment: because `array` has only one element

Comment: The input doesn't contain `","`. It should have two or more to be able to use `array[1]` and `array[2]`.

Comment: no it contains definitely thees are my rows in the file 
Chenty,Rafi,01.25.1850 

Kaytser,Rafi,01.25.1855

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: by any chance is there an empty line or a line with only spaces or anything like that in the file?

Comment: Just add  `System.out.println(str);
  System.out.println("size="+array.length);` to your code, you are probably not on the line you expect.

Comment: same as @sandy.sk is there a last empty line?

Comment: the code is generated by this code public void save(Collection<Book> b) {
  try (PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(this.file);) {
   for (Book book : b) {
    String str = "" + book.getName() + "," + book.getAuthor() + ","
      + book.getDate() + "\n";
    print.println(str);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }

 }
FromFIleToDB fdao = new FromFIleToDB("file.txt","root", "");  
  Collection<Book> col = new ArrayList<>();
  Book b = new Book("Chenty", "Rafi", "01.25.1850");
  Book c = new Book("Kaytser", "Rafi", "01.25.1855");
  col.add(b);
  col.add(c);
  fdao.save(col);

Comment: Please add any clarification to your question itself (using the edit link) - *not* in the comments please.

Comment: The code you use to fill the file is not relevant, the content of the file is.

Comment: @StephaneM,  I ddnt understand this is the content of the file 
dff,Rafi,01.25.1850

hjsk,Rafi,01.25.1855

Comment: Thanks people I found the problem, I was putting "\n" to the end of each line

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. check the content of the file, how many ',' char does it have in each line, it should have at least 2
2. check the size of the array, it should be at least 3 in each read iteration, since you are accessing `array[2]`

It seems that the array  at a certain line or iteration doesn't have 3 items, maybe one or two.

example:

```
line 1: aaa,bbb,ccc   //2 ',' => array={"aaa","bbb","ccc"} this is fine
line 2: ddd,eee       //1 ',' => array={"ddd","eee"} this causes the
                      // exception since array[2] does not exist NULL
line 3: empty         //0 ',' => array={} this causes the exception
```

If you are not sure of what is happening run the following code:

```
    try(Reader reader = new FileReader(this.file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myBook", this.userName,
                this.pass);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String str;          
        while((str = br.readLine()) != null&&str.split(",").length>=3){

            String[] array = str.split(",");
            statement.executeUpdate("Insert Into myBook.book 
(name,author,pubDate) values('"+array[0]+"', '"+ array[1]+"', '"+array[2]+"')");
        }

    }
```

If the above code run without error then at least one line doesn't have 2 ',' chars
if the application still firing the same error then it will be something else.

Comment: it contains 2 ',' chars and i checked the array, its size is 3